# Passing URI to REST API which will redirect it to processed URI

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I've exposed a REST API (GET).This will take relative URI and base URI as inputs and redirected to processed URI.
How shall I pass this relativeURI or baseURI? relativeURI may have special characters like "&"
I can go with POST request with URIs in the body but I would prefect GET request.
These might be amateur approaches

Approach1: Using @RequestParam
@RequestParam String relativeURI, @RequestParam String baseURI
But the problem is relativeURI has characters like & which needs to be encoded before passing it to the REST API

Approach2: Using @PathVariable
@PathVariable in the REST API for relativeURI and base URI as @RequestParam. But this will ignore extra pathVariables

Approach1:

```
@GetMapping("app/DeviceResolution/")public void getPrefix(@RequestParam(value= "baseURI",required=false) String baseURI, @RequestParam("relativeURI") String relativeURI,HttpServletResponse response ) 
    {
//processing
response.sendRedirect(finalURI);
}
```

Approach2:

```
@GetMapping("app/DeviceResolution/{relativeURI}")public void getPrefix(@RequestParam(value= "baseURI",required=false) String baseURI, @PathVariable String relativeURI,HttpServletResponse response ) 
    {
//processing
response.sendRedirect(finalURI);
}
```

GET API -> app/DeviceResolution

relativeURI -> new/category&sub&banner.png

baseURI -> https://www.google.com/

finalURI -> https://www.google.com/processedData..../new/category&sub&banner.png

Comment: You can use the first approach. The special relativeURI will be a string so you will not have any problem as long as you do not mess up with special characters.